# Authenticating sessions for multiple platforms (Android, iOS, Web, etc.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I have not seen this addressed on the web, and I think it is something of importance. Right now, I'm building a product that will have an Android app, iOS app and also a website. A user could be simultaneously logged into each of these apps. This is something one could do with Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc.

There is an issue with the current paradigm though. The current paradigm for authentication for an Android app is passing an `auth_token` param between the front-end and back-end. When the user logs in, one gets generated. When the user logs out, the `auth_token` gets set to `null` in the database. If you were using this token to track sessions between an iOS app, Android app and website, you'd run into issues quickly.

The most common one: If a user is logged in via Android & website and logs out of the website, this will also have the side effect of logging them out of the Android app because the `auth_token` is now `null` in the DB, and there is nothing to match the `auth_token` being sent in by the request from the Android app.

I have thought of one solution, but I don't know if it is optimal or if it is the way this thing is handled in other large projects. If there is a better solution, do tell.

My solution:

Every request contains an `Origin` header. If it comes from the website, this header should hold the value `Application`. If it comes from the Android app, it should hold the value `Android`, and if it comes from the iOS app, it should hold the value `iOS`. This would require three separate DB columns. An `auth_token` for the web platform, Android platform and iOS platform.

If you decided to start supporting Windows phones, you'd need to rebuild your session handler for Windows as well.

That being said, this does keep the entire project and its constituents accountable and knowing of the fact that we're about to support a new front-end. However, it seems a tad problematic to me.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way most do this? Am I overthinking this? Am I wrong in my logic somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is Devise an option for you? You can use it without Rememberable (http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable).

Comment: I actually do use `Devise` for logging in, logging out and registering. I don't use it for the authenticating utility though. It is great for web-apps. Once you start porting with Android and iOS, you need to use auth-tokens.